# Is it possible to change color of specific keyboard keys in iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

I would like to know if is there any possibility to change background color  of specific numeric keys in UIKeyboard of type DecimalPad. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no supported method to modify the system keypad. Create your own keyboard and customize as you need.

Comment: Ok it's clear for me, thank you for quick info @maddy